# DataGrid with TemplateColumn. Performance Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, virtualization

I have a DataGrid with 3 Template columns that all look something like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{userInterface:Translation Description}"
                        Width="2*"
                        IsReadOnly="True"
                        SortMemberPath="Model.Translation"
                        Visibility="{Binding Path=DataContext.(viewModel:ParameterGridViewModel.ShowDescriptionColumn), Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell"
                BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible"
                    Value="False" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="viewModel:ParameterViewModel">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Translation}"
                        ToolTip="{Binding Model.Translation}"
                        TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The `Virtualization` is enabled and working (I did check it with Snoop). Filling the `DataGrid` with about 1000 rows takes ~500ms. If I replace the `TemplateColumns` to `DataGridTextColumns` the performance is significant better (50-100ms) even though the `Template` only contains a `TextBlock`.

Why is the `TemplateColumn` Performance so bad? How can i get a Templateable `DataGrid` that is performing good with this amount of items (Actually it is hilarious that 1000 items limit the WPF `DataGrid`). Event the `DataGridTextColumn` Performance is unacceptable.

Comment: Performance issue can be caused by uggly styles. Are you using custom or default styles ?

Comment: @synapse custom styles for about everything, what is the purpose of using WPF with default styles, it looks like winforms ^^. What styles could be a problem?

Comment: Have you tried to use default style (by commenting yours) ? Just to see the impact. Performances can be killed by too many/inadapted use of RelativeResource/FindAncestor for instance.

Comment: Commenting out the DataGrid Style does not help